# Data type conditions in python

Tags: python, if-statement, types, conditional-statements, type-conversion

How do i give a condition in which for example; if x is not an integer print("type an integer")[image: this image should explain better]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your sample code, your best bet is to catch the `ValueError` and try again:

```
def get_int():
    try:
        return int(input('Type an integer:'))
    except ValueError:
        print("Not an int.  Try again.")
        return get_int()
```

The reason is because if the user enters a non-integer string, then the exception gets raised before you have a chance to check the type, so `isinstance` doesn't really help you too much here.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be casting the value to into and handle the exception:

```
try:
    parsed = int(user_input)
    print ("int")

except:
    print ("not int")
```